# Preempt a process by a timer interrupt

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, preemption

There are two processes (P-A and P-B) running on the same CPU core. Process B is multithreaded. I want process A to be preempted after every 2 microseconds by a thread of Process B.

Is it possible to write a timer interrupt (or anything else) to preempt process A after a fixed interval of time (in microseconds)?

Comment: in a user-space program?

Comment: Yes, Daniel. I could have used alarm(), as suggested by @Chris, but I want to refrain from using signal mechanism as it itself takes at least 1-2 microseconds. Is it possible without signaling?

Comment: Linux itself is not optimized for this use-case. But there are projects which implement such techniques (real-time aka RT) in the kernel. Without a modified kernel I don't believe you have something better than alarm. A short google search for "linux real-time" found the following: RTLinux, RTAI, LibeRTOS, Xenomai

Comment: @Scissor, you could do it in kernel space which now supports high-resolution timer.

Answer (score 1):

`alarm` system call is what you need. According to its [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm), `alarm()` arranges for a SIGALRM signal to be delivered to the calling process in seconds seconds. You can register your signal handler for SIGALRM by `signal/sigaction` interface.